# How do I supress error related to build constraints in syscall/js?

Tags: go, webassembly

I'm writing a WASM program using Golang. Import of `syscall/js` causes `build constraints exclude all go files...` error by static check. The program builds just fine with right flags: `GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o frontend/calc.wasm internal/calc/calc.go`

However, static check ceases to work until this one error is fixed. How can I suppress this error while keeping import of `syscall/js`?

Project structure:

```
frontend // files that will be served on the web, compiled .wasm file will go there
internal
  L calc // a directory of a program that will be compiled into WASM
      L calc.go
      L ...
main.go // a file server
go.mod
go.sum
```

Comment: Since the program you are trying to run `staticcheck` on targets `js/wasm`, did you try running `staticcheck` with `GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm`?

Comment: @JimB I tried this via editing `settings.json` of VSCode. Errors disappeared but I presume that, this sets `GOOS` and `GOARCH` globally which I don't need because `main.go` still needs to be compiled for normal `x86`.